# Calling a Web Method from ASPX Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I'm trying to figure out a way that I can call a Web Method (located as a public static method in the code behind of an aspx page) from another ASPX Code Behind page.

This is the code behind of Page A.aspx

```
public partial class PageA : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // other code not relevant is here  
    }

    [WebMethod(true)]
    public static string GetStringInfo()
    {
         // do some stuff here to build my string
         // return string
    }
}
```

On page B, I need to be able to call GetStringInfo() during page load or some other event to get the information. the GetStringInfo() is fairly complex and for reasons outside of my control, can't be moved elsewhere or rebuilt presently.

How can I consume the web method above from another page's code behind?

I've tried instantiating a copy of the other page (PageB), such as:

```
public partial class PageB : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       PageA page = new PageA();
       page.GetStringInfo();        
    }
}
```

The problem here is since it's dynamically compiled, I don't have an easy namespace to reference and access. I've tried adding one, and it ignores it.

This project is on .net 3.5, C#, and is a web site project (not a web application).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's static, call it with PageA.GetStringInfo();

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting with the current code snippet?

Comment: The problem I'm getting is it's not finding that PageA even exists. So as I try to instantiate the page, it just asks me to generate a method stub for it instead of finding the class of the other page.

Comment: Are the 2 pages in the same namespace?  If there is no namespace declared on the 2 classes, try explictly declaring both pages in the same namespace.

Comment: @Steve I have tried explicity giving both a namespace, but as this is dynamically compiled (web site, not web application) it pretty much ignores the namespacing outside of App_Code.

Comment: BTW: very bad design to make pages inter-dependent like that. A page should rely on entities and logic not on another page and controls it contains... in fact since the GetStringInfo is static you can't even access page controls from it and it tells you that such method has to be somewhere else and not in the page.

Comment: I understand it's bad design, however as is often the case, I'm not the one who designed it, I'm simply working within how it was done. Believe me, I wish I could redesign it and do it properly at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `GetStringInfo` method is static you don't need an instance of `PageA` to invoke it:

```
public partial class PageB : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string info = PageA.GetStringInfo();        
    }
}
```

Comment: This simply returns "does not exist in the current context" for PageA's class when I try to do that.

Comment: @Delebrin, then you are not showing us everything. The code as you have shown it should work the way I showed you. Also make sure that if the `PageA` class is defined in a different namespace than the `PageB`, this namespace was brought into scope. By the way, are those 2 pages in the same ASP.NET application?

Comment: They are both within the same Web Site solution. It isn't a true web application, which is what I believe is part of the problem. I can add namespaces explicity to both pages, but the namespace is ignored since the pages are dynamically compiled.

Comment: @Delebrin, if it's a web site you might get errors in Visual Studio at design time. Ignore them. Run your site. It will work. The problem is that in a website there are no assemblies compiled at design time. So when you are inside PageB, the VS designer doesn't really know what the PageA contains. It's stupid but you shouldn't worry. You won't get any Intellisense but when you run your site you can even place breakpoints inside to ensure that it works. I suspect that you were confused by the lack of Intellisense.